# BlackBerry Non-Blocking UDP API

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to know, is there a non-Blocking UDP API call in Blackberry.
Is there any api i need to call so that i can make it as a non-blocking one ?

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but is there an advantage to using non-blocking instead of just running blocking I/O on its own dedicated thread?

Comment: blocking I/O  would block the progress of a program while the communication is in progress, leaving system resources idle. i am still learning about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface UDPDatagramConnection performs blocking I/O operations, I honestly don't know of a non-blocking option.

Comment: Its better if you write this as comment instead of in answer.

Comment: @harry why? that is the answer there *isn't* a non-blocking I/O function in blackberry it doesn't exist. I am pretty sure there are NO non-blocking I/O functions any where in Java.

Comment: @drubin: yes it can be the answer but he has written answer as he is not confident. So I commented it. If he give this answer as comment and you find it as answer then you can ask him to write it as answer and accept it.

Comment: @Harry true but I wasn't the OP, so I couldn't ask anything :)